# String split, words including accented characters

Tags: java, regex

I'm using this regex:

```
x.split("[^a-zA-Z0-9']+");
```

This returns an array of strings with letters and/or numbers.

If I use this:

```
String name = "CEN01_Automated_TestCase.java";
String[] names = name.Split.split("[^a-zA-Z0-9']+");
```

I got:

```
CEN01
Automated
TestCase
Java
```

But if I use this:

```
String name = "CEN01_Automação_Caso_Teste.java";
String[] names = name.Split.split("[^a-zA-Z0-9']+");
```

I got:

```
CEN01
Automa
o
Caso
Teste
Java
```

How can I modify this regex to include accented characters? (á,ã,õ, etc...)

Comment: If Java support unicode properties `[^\p{L}]` would be quite robust. Don't know if it does though...

Comment: @Wrikken: It does. Java 7 even supports `\w` and `\b` in a Unicode-sensible way.

Comment: Nice, I was just to lazy to look it up, but duly noted ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

> Categories that behave like the `java.lang.Character boolean ismethodname` methods (except for the deprecated ones) are available through the same `\p{prop}` syntax where the specified property has the name `javamethodname`.

Since `Character` class contains `isAlphabetic` method you can use

```
name.split("[^\\p{IsAlphabetic}0-9']+");
```

You can also use

```
name.split("(?U)[^\\p{Alpha}0-9']+");
```

but you will need to use `UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS` flag which can be used by adding `(?U)` in regex.

Comment: Glad you like it. You can find many useful informations in [Pattern documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) :)

Answer (score 2):

I would check out the [Java Documentation on Regular Expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html). There is a unicode section which I believe is what you may be looking for.

EDIT: Example

Another way would be to match on the character code you are looking for. For example

```
\uFFFF where FFFF is the hexadecimal number of the character you are trying to match.
```

Example:  `\u00E0 matches à`

Realize that the backslash will need to be escaped in Java if you are using it as a string literal.

Read more about it [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html).

Comment: You are probably right, but my vote is for the one that submits a working example here.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
String[] names = name.split("[^a-zA-Z0-9'\\p{L}]+");
```

`System.out.println(Arrays.toString(names));` Will output:

**[CEN01, Automação, Caso, Teste, java]**

See [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#ubc) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Why not split on the separator characters?

```
String[] names = name.split("[_.]");
```

Comment: Thanks! It helped me to came with a solution!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of blacklisting all the characters you don't want, you could always whitlist the characters you want like :

```
^[^<>%$]*$
```

The expression [^(many characters here)] just matches any character that is not listed.

But that is a personnal opinion.